# Codeception, define another name for directory "tests" in bootstrap command

Tags: codeception

i need to use another name for the directory, codeception holds the test suites in. My original problem is, that I am working on windows and must maintain a project, where there are already PHPUnit tests in a directory called "Tests".
Now I would like to use codeception for my own tests, which are held in a directory called "tests".
Even if the project itself is in a linux environment which is case sensitive, my IDE is on windows. There I can see those two folders but windows sees the same content in it.

So the quickest solution for me would be to rename either PHPUnits "Tests" or Codeceptions "tests" to some different name.

In case of codeception I see, that that directory can be modified in codeception.yml configuration after a test environment has been bootstraped.
I wonder it it is possible already within the bootstrap command.

Comment: I suggest to move phpunit tests to tests/unit directory. Codeception can run phpunit tests.

Comment: True, but those PHPUnit tests are meant to be run by another test framework, so I can not touch that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analysing the sourcecode of codeceptions bootstrap class, it seems that this directory name is hardcoded there, so there is no way to botstrap a testsuite with a different directory, tnah "test".
I think it's OK to mark my own question as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change `paths: tests:` setting as documented in http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Configuration

`paths:
    # where the modules stored
    tests: codeception-tests`

Comment: Thank you. I do know that, see my question. I would prefer an option for the bootstrap command. But after analysing the sourcecode of codeceptions bootstrap class, it seems that this directory name is hardcoded there.